# show an analytic function $f$ has primitive on domain $D$ iff $\int_\gamma f dz = 0$ for every closed path $\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to show if $f$ is analytic, then it has a primitive on some domain $D$ if and only if

$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$$

for every closed path $\gamma$, in $D$. So supposing $f$ has a primitive, by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus, if $\gamma$ is a path from $a$ to $b$, then

$$\int_\gamma f dz = F(b)-F(a)$$

where $F$ is the primitive of $f$ but $\gamma$ is closed so the end points agree forcing $F(b)=F(a). $ thus the integral is zero.

Is this correct for the forward direction? And for the backward direction we assume

$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$$

for every closed path $\gamma$, how do I show $f$ has a primitive? Is it correct to say since the integral of $f$ is zero, the integral exists? Btw, sorry if this is a dup, I couldn't find one.

Comment: Hint: Choose a point $p \in D$, and define $F(z)$ in terms of an integral of $f$ along a path from $p$ to $z$. Show that this is well-defined because it doesn't matter which path from $p$ to $z$ is used. Show that $F$ is actually a primitive of $f$ on $D$.

Comment: Yes, the first direction is ok. For the other fix a point $a\in D$ and define $F(z)$ to be the integral of $f$ along a path from $a$ to $z$. The condition allows you to prove that this definition is independent on the path. It does depend on $a$, but a different selection will make the definition of $F$ change by the constant that is the integral of $f$ from $a$ to the new point.

Comment: is it independent of the path since it holds for any simple closed curve @user85667

Comment: @aschepler does it not matter what path I choose as any simple closed path has zero integral thus thee condition holds for any path?

Comment: @user85667 do you mean fix some $a \in D$ then define $F(z):=\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ where $\gamma:[a,z] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ is closed?

Comment: It is independent of the path because if $g_1,g_2$ are two paths starting both at $a$ and ending at $z$, then the path $g$ that follows $g_1$ first and then $g_2$ in reverse is closed. The integral on $g$ is zero. Therefore, $0=\int_g=\int_{g_1}-\int_{g_2}$ gives that $\int_{g_1}=\int_{g_2}$.

Comment: It is not $\gamma:[a,z]\to\mathbb{C}$. The points $a,z\in D\subset \mathbb{C}$. It is $\gamma:[0,1]\to D\subset\mathbb{C}$, such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=z$. This is what is a path in $D$ from $a$ to $z$.

Comment: good catch @user85667 !! and did you meant first then $g_2$? in your above comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138593/discussion-between-hossien-s-mymathyourmath-and-user85667).